Why "Power & battery" stuck at spinning circle for 4 hours?
Yesterday, I left laptop on for 4 hours, and this circle kept spinning for 4 hours! See GIF.
Then I clicked "Restart". But this circle spun for 2 hours, before I shut down without fast boot.
Today, since boot, this circle has been spinning for 3 hours now.



Reboot and try again. As for the reason it's impossible to know among hundreds of possible causes.

A few years ago I was attending Six Sigma Quality Training and the trainer asked Why Microsoft does not go for Six Sigma processes. I said, because their products have a million defects per 3.4 opportunities.

@ChanganAuto thanks. I edited my post. reboot doesn't solve problem.

It's (obviously) a bug, most likely located in the new "modern" Settings app. No matter what data the app gets from the "power & battery" hardware, showing a spinner for 4 hours is unambigously the wrong way to present it to the user.
There's probably nothing you can do about it. If you don't feel frustrated enough already, you can submit feedback in Windows Feedback Hub and watch it being ignored.
The workaround most likely leading to success would be to start the old "classic" Control Panel with Win+r control Enter and try to find the option you want to change there.

From the details you've provided, it's impossible to say why this happened.
Giving a computer that sort of time for a simple operation like this is entirely unnecessary - if it doesn't complete in ~30 seconds, it likely never will - the probability of it actually completing drops off very sharply.
Close and reopen the application, or go for a full reboot. If it reoccurs then start looking into logs, newly installed software/drivers, etc...
